# case within case using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have 3 columns `doc_date`, `chem_date`, `st_date`

all 3 columns belong to different tables:

```
doc
doc_date      count(x)
01-02-2012      2
02-02-2012      3

chem
chem_date      count(x)
04-02-2012      1
06-02-2012      0

stock
st_date      count(x)
01-02-2012      1
03-02-2012      5
```

I want to write select clause like this

```
case doc_date 
    when '01' then count(x),
    case chem_date
    when '01' then count(x),
    case st_date 
    when '01' then count(x)
    end as '01',
case doc_date 
    when '02' then count(x),
    case chem_date
    when '02' then count(x),
    case st_date 
    when '02' then count(x)
    end as '02',

....up to 31 days
```

If some case statements have an entry on same date e.g if `doc_date` and `st_date` both exist on '01-02-2012' then their respective count should be added to the final `count(x)` means `count(x) + count(x)`

So, the answer should be:

```
01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09 10  11  12.. up to 31 days
3   3   5   1       0                          count(x) value for particular date
```

Explanation of the output: Here, the starting value for date 01 is 2 for `doc` table  and for `stock` table the value is 1. So, the final value will become addition of them which is 3

The same rule will be applicable for others.

Any suggestions how can I achieve this output in SQL? Or any other way?

Comment: Basically, if you don't improve it, nobody will answer because they won't trust you'll mark their question as answered. So it is for your own benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pseudo code showing how it can be done:

```
select

case when date_format(doc_date,"%d") = '01' then sum_x else null end as '01',
case when date_format(doc_date,"%d") = '02' then sum_x else null end as '02',
--and etc

from (

    select doc_date, sum(doc_x) as sum_x              --sum the x value
    from
    (

        select doc_date,doc_x                         --combine all 3 table stuff
        from doc a

        union all

        select chem_date,chem_x
        from chem a

        union all

        select st_date,st_x
        from st a
    ) h
    group by doc_date               --use first col name as the union's col name

) g
limit 1,1
```

If the `doc`, `chem` and `st` are combined using `joins` and have different schema, you may need to do pivot, either using multiple join to itself or use `case... when...`:

```
select

case when date_format(doc_date,"%d") = '01' then sum_x else null end as '01',
case when date_format(doc_date,"%d") = '02' then sum_x else null end as '02',
--and etc

from (

        select doc_date,                               
               a_x + b_x + c_x as sum_x            --sum them according to date
        from (select ... from doc where ...) a
        left join (select ... from chem where ...) b on a.doc_date=b.doc_date and --some join condition
        left join (select ... from st where ...) c on a.doc_date=c.doc_date and --some join condition

) g
limit 1,1
```

I am working with an ambiguous question here, so clarify as needed,

Comment: your way is definitely good, but I have joined these tables using different conditions, and here we have used union all , (consider doc, chem ,stock as a separate clause like this way)  select * from(select .....from doc left join.....)left join (select *From chem left join ..)in this way, so how can include your answer in these clause?

Comment: I have tried your way without limit 1,1 then I am getting one row, but value of sum_x for  26th day of particular month displaying for all 1-31 days, it should be displayed for only 26th of that month.?

Comment: @PravinGate i think you will need to change it to string, cut it out and compare them.

Comment: but we are taking them in single quotes already like '01' so they are strings already is it so? if not how we can convert them ?

Comment: If your date column datatype is `datetime`, then you will need to do something like `SUBSTRING( DATE_FORMAT(doc_date,'%d-%m-%Y') ,1,2)`.

Comment: ok, I have already written them in DATE_FORMAT like DATE_FORMAT(cl_doc.date_entered,'%d')as Date, so my question is how our case statements e.g case '01' will understood directly this date? as there is no mapping between them.

Comment: @PravinGate i edited the answer and see if it works, I was not being clear.